# Quiero formater la fecha de la BD pero no quiero que la cambie dependiendo del pais

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola amigos quiero imprimir el siguiente dato que viene de BD.

```
2022-06-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Este dato quiero formaterarlo, lo hago con la libreria moment().format()

```
moment(contentUser["AttemptDate​"]).format("MMMM Do YYYY HH:mm:ss"
```

y la respuesta de este dato es:

```
May 31st 2022 19:00:00
```

si se dan cuenta me lo pasa a 5 horas antes ya que estoy en colombia y el GMT y quiero que me formatee el dato sin que me modifique la fecha por GMT

Answer (score 0):

Las fechas/horas tienen siempre implícita una zona horaria, incluso lo que se da en llamar hora universal (UTC), que es igual a GMT = 0 (Greenwich Mean Time). En tu caso para mantener la hora de la base de datos, tienes que convertir la fecha a la zona horaria que tengas en la base de datos. Si quieres mantener exactamente la misma fecha hora puedes asumir que el GMT de la base de datos es 0 o bien pasarlo a UTC, entonces puedes hacer algo así:

```
moment.utc('2022-06-01T00:00:00.000Z').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```